# MySQL master replication after online

Tags: mysql, relational-database, replication, database-replication

I am new to MySQL replication.

If master is offline and slave database has been updated by application then will it replicate master database when master comes online or connect with network?

I have billing application each machine (slave) will have there own MySQL database and they will replicate master database but something master databass won't be avaliable becauae of network issue.

Comment: No. MySQL replication is a one-way replication. If your application will automatically switch from master to slave, don't make it roll back automatically. In my implementation I swap the role s.t. slave becomes master and master becomes slave. My friends like to stop the system and get everything in sync and use the original master as master again. So its up to your architecture design.

Comment: I am developing end user application,  users have no idea about mysql i need to handle all these in my application. Do you think i should try some other replication third party tool? Like jumpmind symmetric or something else. I heard mariaDB replication is better then mysql.